Clarify my understanding of returning an object with attribute created on heap
so I have overloaded the addition operator like this:
outside of the class, I have
template <typename ValueType>
class array_vec;

template <typename ValueType>
array_vec<ValueType> operator + (const array_vec<ValueType> &vec1, const array_vec<ValueType> &vec2);

and in my class, in public, I have
    friend array_vec<ValueType> operator + (const array_vec<ValueType> &vec1, const array_vec<ValueType> &vec2) {
        array_vec<ValueType> new_arra_vec(vec1.current_pos + vec2.current_pos + 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < vec1.current_pos + 1; i++) {
            new_arra_vec.row[i] = vec1.row[i];
            new_arra_vec.col[i] = vec1.col[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vec2.current_pos + 1; i++) {
            new_arra_vec.row[i + vec1.current_pos + 1] = vec2.row[i];
            new_arra_vec.col[i + vec1.current_pos + 1] = vec2.col[i];
        }
        // new_arra_vec.print_all();
        std::cout << &new_arra_vec << std::endl;
        return new_arra_vec;
    }

and the constructor it called is:
template <typename ValueType>
array_vec<ValueType>::array_vec(int size) {
    row = new ValueType[size + 10]();
    col = new ValueType[size + 10]();
    current_pos = size - 1;
    actual_size = size + 10;
    std::cout << "default vector containing int 0 created" << std::endl;
}

and I did this in my main:

    std::string a[4] = {"2,3,4,5", "how are you", "hi", "you"};
    std::string b[4] = {"hi", "how are you", "S", "D"};
    std::string c[6] = {"what", "how ", "ck", "ou", "2,30", "5"};


    array_vec<std::string> arrayveca(a, b, 4);
    array_vec<std::string> arrayvecb(b, a, 4);
    array_vec<std::string> arrayvecc(c, c, 6);

    array_vec<std::string> arrayvecd = arrayveca + arrayvecc;
    std::cout << &arrayvecd << std::endl;



I also have my copy constructor implemented like this:
template <typename ValueType>
array_vec<ValueType>::array_vec(const array_vec<ValueType>& src){
    this->deepCopy(src);
}

template <typename ValueType>
array_vec<ValueType>& array_vec<ValueType>::operator = (const array_vec<ValueType>& src) {
    if (this != &src) {
        deepCopy(src);
    }
    return *this;
} //copy from the source data into the current object


template <typename ValueType>
void array_vec<ValueType>::deepCopy(const array_vec<ValueType>& src) {

    delete[] this->row;
    delete[] this->col;

    this->row = new ValueType[src.actual_size]();
    this->col = new ValueType[src.actual_size]();
    this->current_pos = src.current_pos;
    this->actual_size = src.actual_size;

    for (int i = 0; i < src.current_pos + 1; i++) {
        this->row[i] = src.row[i];
        this->col[i] = src.col[i];
    }

}

I am practicing and I thought that object arrayvecd would have a different address from the local object new_arra_vec as I am returning a copy i.e. the local new_arra_vec would be destroyed once the addition operation function returned a copy of it.
but it turns out arrayvecd and new_arra_vec have the same address
So I expect arrayvecd to have a different address but it turns out to be the same. (So I expect arrayvecd to be a copy of new_arra_vec (with a copy of its attribute that pointed to the same address on heap) and have a different address from new_arra_vec .
Is it because how I overloaded the assignment operator? I am confused here.

It's just the compiler optimising away the extra object. new_arra_vec and arrayvecd don't exist at the same time, so there's no need for them to have different addresses.

@john thanks. So is my understanding "arrayvecd to be a copy of new_arra_vec (with a copy of its attribute that pointed to the same address on heap) " correct?

You have not shown your copy constructor, so I have no idea what it does. But I hope it's not copying pointers (which is what your statement is implying to me).

The TLDR is implement your assignment and copy constructor correctly, and don't worry about the compiler optimising away calls that copy objects. As long as your implementations are correct, your code will be correct, whatever tricks the compiler uses.
